# Перенос значений из Input text в div с использованием each JQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, получаю значения из `input text` так:

```
$('.input').each(function(i){   


});
```

Возможно ли сразу переписывать полученные значения в `div` внутри функции `each`?
Количество `inputs` может динамически изменяться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

```
$('.input').each(function(i, e){   
    $('#mydiv').text($(e).val());
});
```

Comment: скорее $('#mydiv').text( $('#mydiv').text() + $(e).val());